# directive 'catch_workers_output = yes' don't work as I want

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, php-fpm, log-files

I have CentOS 7 with apache 2.4.35 with pmp event  and php-fpm

all works fine but all php errors are go to one big file for all my virtual hosts.

I read all docs about it and find that

```
catch_workers_output = yes
```

might be help me. I think that this directive send all php errors to apache log file but there is no luck.

I don't really know what I should now.

here is my php.conf

```
<Proxy "unix:/var/run/php-fpm/default.sock|fcgi://php-fpm">
 # we must declare a parameter in here (doesn't matter which) or it'll not register the proxy ahead of time
 ProxySet disablereuse=off
</Proxy>
# Redirect to the proxy
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler proxy:fcgi://php-fpm
</FilesMatch>

#
# Allow php to handle Multiviews
#
AddType text/html .php
#
# Add index.php to the list of files that will be served as directory
# indexes.
#
DirectoryIndex index.php

ProxyErrorOverride on
```

p.s.
I think that individual pool per site will solve the problem but I think that it get really more memory, because every pool need to create empty slots to start serving...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if I comment out this line in file /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

```
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
```

like here:

```
;php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
```

all php errors go to the apache log files (individual per site)

There is no need to touch **catch_workers_output** . Leave it commented out!

```
;catch_workers_output = no
```

Comment: This is what I did to direct output to the VHOSTS log files, but all error_log calls are concatenated into a single line.  I haven't figured that out yet.